# WordPress Simple CSS PostGrid Background-Color Problem

Tags: css, wordpress, background-color

Im looking to create a demosite (http://emc.ow-media.de/main)

I want to create a grey border (#eeeeee) around the Post Grid-Elements in the top and the bottom.
Where is my mistake?

I set Custom CSS for the bottom post-grids like this:

````
.layer-wrapper layout-105
 {
 background-color: #eee;
} ```
````

Comment: It's difficult to understand, what you want the items to look like in the end. Can you upload a sketch of the desired look?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it correctly you need to change the selector to: `.layer-wrapper.layout-105`

You are basically trying to select an element inside the `.layer-wrapper` called `<layout-105>`, that of course does not exist. When you want to select a class don't forget the dot in front. In this case you want to select an element with two classes applied, so don't use a whitespace between the classes.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer:

Im looking for this result:

https://ibb.co/bbJHv5t

I´m able to edit the style temporarily in FF (look in the right marked area) - but i don´t know how to write the correct css element.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add border use border property not background

you forget to add "." in layout-105 & both class combine with "." not use space betwwen two same div classs.

Result
https://ibb.co/74hjDjK

use this:

```
.layer-wrapper.layout-105 {
     border-top: 2px solid #000;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```